# WeakReference too weak?

Tags: c#, events, weak-references

I've implemented this WeakEvent Delegate but for some reason it only works for a few seconds, and after that it stops working:

```
public class WeakEventHandler<TE>  where TE : EventArgs
{
    private readonly Action<WeakEventHandler<TE>> _unsubscriber;
    private readonly WeakReference<EventHandler<TE>> _targetRef;
    private readonly EventHandler<TE> _handler;


    public WeakEventHandler(EventHandler<TE> eventReceiver, Action<WeakEventHandler<TE>> unsubscriber)
    {
        _unsubscriber = unsubscriber;
        _targetRef = new WeakReference<EventHandler<TE>>(eventReceiver);
        _handler = Invoke;
    }

    public void Invoke(object sender, TE e)
    {
        EventHandler<TE> method;

        if (_targetRef.TryGetTarget(out method))
        {
            method(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            _unsubscriber(this);
        }

    }

    public static implicit operator EventHandler<TE>(WeakEventHandler<TE> weh)
    {
        return weh._handler;
    }
}

public static class EventHandlerUtils
{
    public static EventHandler<TE> MakeWeak<TE>(this EventHandler<TE> eventReceiver, Action<WeakEventHandler<TE>> unsubscriber) where TE : EventArgs
    {
        return new WeakEventHandler<TE>(eventReceiver, unsubscriber);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    private EventHandler<MouseInteractionArgs> _mouseInteractionDelegate;

    public event EventHandler<MouseInteractionArgs> MouseAction
    {
        add
        {
            _mouseInteractionDelegate += value.MakeWeak(handler => _mouseInteractionDelegate -= handler );
        }

        remove
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This is a weak Event, dont worry about unsubscribing");
        }
    }
```

I never stop referencing the owner of the method, so I dont know why it is not working, do delegates behave different?

Comment: At first glance, it all looks fine to me. That is, you wrapped "eventReceiver" in a WeakReference<T>, and then never retain that "eventReceiver" reference anywhere else. So of course it gets collected.

Comment: but the "eventreceiver" is owned by the instance of the method and that instances is always referenced so it gets copied  or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but the "eventreceiver" is owned by the instance of the method

Sorry, but you have that backwards. The "eventReceiver" is the delegate instance that you are adding to the MouseAction event. That delegate instance retains a reference to the target object and MethodInfo, not the other way around. There's no code retaining the reference to the delegate instance except your WeakReference and of course by design that's not enough to keep the object alive.

Comment: its 3:56 am where I am, I have no idea of what you are saying I already renamed eventReceiver to subscriber ( obviously didnt work ) and it didnt work, what do I need to change?

Comment: Renaming a variable doesn't do anything except change that variable's name. What do you need to change? I'm not sure, since it's not entirely clear to me what the goal is here. It looks like maybe you are trying to design a system that is robust against the "object fails to be collected due to forgotten event subscriptions" bug. If so, then the object that needs to be retained by the WeakReference is the delegate's _target_, not the delegate itself. Of course, that does mean that the delegate itself could still be left around...but you can add code to clean up by looking for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer I was able to fix the Weakeventhandler:

```
public class WeakEventHandler<TE> where TE : EventArgs
{
    private delegate void OpenEventHandler(object target, object sender, TE e);

    private readonly WeakReference _targetRef;
    private readonly OpenEventHandler _openHandler;

    private readonly Action<WeakEventHandler<TE>> _unsubscriber;
    private readonly EventHandler<TE> _handler;


    public WeakEventHandler(EventHandler<TE> subscriber, Action<WeakEventHandler<TE>> unsubscriber)
    {
        _unsubscriber = unsubscriber;
        _targetRef = new WeakReference(subscriber.Target);
        _handler = Invoke;


        var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof (object), "target");
        var sender = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "sender");
        var args = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TE), "args");

        _openHandler =
            Expression.Lambda<OpenEventHandler>(
                Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(target, subscriber.Target.GetType()), subscriber.Method, sender,
                    args),target,sender,args).Compile();
    }

    public void Invoke(object sender, TE e)
    {
        var t = _targetRef.Target;

        if (t != null)
        {
            _openHandler(t, sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            _unsubscriber(this);
        }

    }

    public static implicit operator EventHandler<TE>(WeakEventHandler<TE> weh)
    {
        return weh._handler;
    }
}
```

I'm building a component-based system, where components of an Object sometimes need to interact with for example mouse events, and I dont want to unregister each component for each object I remove from the world.

Comment: One slight caveat with this approach is that a memory leak could occur if an unbounded number of subscribers could be created and abandoned for an event which is never actually triggered (e.g. class objects subscribe to a "collection changed" event, but the collection never actually gets changed).

Comment: mm I'dont think so, if the objects are "abadoned", they would be collected, since the event is only holding a weak reference to them.

Comment: The objects identified by the weak references would be collectible, but the event wrappers and weak references would all be strongly referenced by the event publisher. If the event fires, all of those event wrappers will get unsubscribed, but unless or until that happens an unbounded number of them may get created and added to the event list.